# Why can't I reference Graphic Raycaster in my gameObject?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a reference to the Graphic Raycaster on my Canvas so that I can enable/disable it. This is what I am doing:

```
shopCanvas.GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster> ().enabled = false;
```

When I hover over the above code in monoDevelop it says "The name GraphicRaycaster does not exist in the current context"

When I try to compile and run the game I get this error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GraphicRaycaster' could not
>   be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Here is a pic of my setup:

[image]

Comment: `CS0246` is usually on the nose. Did you verify the things it's recommending you verify? It seems that the type `GraphicRaycaster` is not available in the context, either because you are missing a `using` directive (that would import its namespace), or because you aren't even referencing the DLL in which the type is declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

To the beginning of your C# code file and compiler will find `GraphicRaycaster`.